# "Is" or "are" for two uncountable words?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

"The commonality and difference among these concepts is/are still unclear. So our paper sheds light on it/them."

[‘Is’ or ‘are’ for two uncountable nouns/subjects](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/234169/is-or-are-for-two-uncountable-nouns-subjects)

According to the above thread, what matters is whether "commonality and difference" is regarded as a compound noun. But I am not sure about this example.

Comment: I personally wouldn't think of them as uncountable, and would write it with the plural: "The commonalities and differences among these concepts ...." -- This isn't a "split the knot" rewrite, but what would have been the most natural way for me to write it in the first place.

Comment: The sugar and the flour are in the cupboard.

Comment: BTW, it should be "between", not "among".

Comment: @Acccumulation only if "these concepts" are known to number two.  The sentence by itself doesn't say how many concepts there are, so "among" is correct.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem "Among" is something shared. "Difference" is not shared. It takes "between", regardless of how many things there are. "The difference between nouns, verbs, and adjectives can be subtle" not "The difference among nouns, verbs, and adjective can be subtle".

Answer (score 8):

There's something of a US/UK usage split regarding the plurality of nouns. For example, [companies](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/is-a-company-e-g-pfizer-singular-or-plural), [public bodies](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/176693/is-government-singular-or-plural), and *[couples / pairs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121773/is-a-couple-of-something-plural-or-singular)* are nearly always singular in AmE, but BrE is often very flexible in this area.

[Here's an example](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Our%20commonality%20and%20difference%20is%22) matching OP's cited usage which seems okay to me as a Brit, but apparently not everyone would accept it...

> *Our **commonality and difference is** sustained by apostolic truth and the promise of the unity of all things in the worship of God*

At least with *that* example, I have no particular objection to using ***are*** instead of ***is***. But that's certainly not the case with *this* example...

> *In a logical sense, **similarity and difference is** a binary relation in which similarity excludes difference, and vice versa*

...where the entire sentence falls apart if you try to change ***is*** to ***are***. I'm just glad that as a Brit I don't have to let things like that bother me!

---

It may be an inviolable rule<sup>1</sup> in AmE that "commonality and difference" must always be syntactically plural in AmE, but that's *not* true of British English.

No-one could object to *The **commonalities and differences are** unclear*, but for the exact version as presented here, I personally prefer the singular verb form. And I very much doubt the *writer* would accept that he made a "mistake".

---

<sup>1</sup> Obviously even in AmE it's not an *inviolable* rule. I'm deliberately exaggerating the scope of a "general principle" that I think is slavishly applied far too often in AmE.

Comment: I've UVd your answer as I think it summarises your point of view well and is a perfectly valid alternative.

Comment: I think the classic example of "couples/pairs" (at least from my school days) is "salt and pepper."  Often used with a singular verb: "Salt and pepper is in aisle 12."

Comment: @PeterJennings: Now you're putting me on the spot! I toyed with the possibility of upvoting Jay's answer when you commented on it earlier (because initial *If we're taking a vote* strongly implies *opinions differ*). But in the end I didn't, because it seemed illogical for me to upvote Jay's answer but *downvote* yours. And - no disrespect intended - I don't want to remove or reverse my downvote against your answer as it stands, because it's effectively claiming that if I disagree, it must be that I don't know "proper" English!

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's OK. If you really think my answer is wrong or doesn't contribute anything to the question then DV it. I also UVd Jays answer because, as I said in a previous comment, he has explained it better than I can.

Comment: @SyntaxJunkie Then there is the exception "Mr and Mrs Smith **are** going on holiday"", you'd never say "Mr and Mrs Smith **is**..."

Answer (score 5):

No, "commonality and difference" is not a compound noun, it's a list of two distinct things. Therefore the correct verb is "are". I know it's gibberish, but if it had been "commonality **of** difference" then it is a compound noun, single item, and would have taken "is"

Comment: I disagree. It's a *stylistic choice* (dependent on *exact* context) whether to treat "commonality and difference" as a singular or plural np. We very rarely use exactly and only those three words as the subject of a verb, but it didn't take me long to find [*Our commonality and difference **is** sustained by apostolic truth and the promise of the unity of all things in the worship of God*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Our+commonality+and+difference+is%22) in Google Books. Which so far as I'm concerned is perfectly good English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm afraid, for once, we must agree to disagree. Jay's answer (below) puts my argument far better than I ever could. Just because something is in print somewhere doesn't make it correct. There are thousands, if not millions of grammatical errors that slip past the proof readers and into print. But as you say, some of it is stylistic not to mention dialect, context or artistic effect.

Comment: The problem, with such a pedantic approach is that sooner or later you have to confront obviously acceptable usages that *don't* fit the simplified (and usually, outdated) rules that collectively we call grammar / syntax. Surely you wouldn't argue with [*In a logical sense, **similarity and difference is** a binary relation in which similarity excludes difference, and vice versa.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22similarity+and+difference+is+a+binary+relatio%22) To my mind, both that and OP's example work much better as a singular np.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As another (retired) software engineer, I'm skating on very thin ice here, but maybe your counterexample is more akin to Jay's very last sentence where "Commonality and difference" are taken as a whole, a concept, rather then two separate items. Then, I am a pedant, the son of a teacher with two teacher aunts, I still think it an anathema if you say, for example, anything other than "different **from**"  . I respectfully suggest that we let it drop now.

Comment: This sounds like an example of the perennial argument we have on here, "Is 'correct English' what some authority wrote in a book, or is it discovered by observing what people actually say in real life?" i.e. is it prescriptive or descriptive. I agree that the fact that someone wrote a grammar rule in a book 200 years ago doesn't bind us all for eternity. But on the other hand, if we say that whatever anyone says is by definition "correct English", then there's no point even having a site like this. Personally, I opt for a middle ground: ...

Comment: ... If a rule is well-established and widely recognized, and makes logical sense, and helps us to understand each other better, then I respect it. If a rule doesn't make sense or adds complexity to the language for no apparent reason other than "because somebody wrote it in a book" (like "never use a preposition to end a sentence with"), then I don't respect it.

Answer (score 5):

If we're taking a vote, I agree with Peter Jennings! "Commonality and difference" are two things and thus require a plural verb.

Yes, one might say that the phrase "commonality and difference" is two ways of saying the same thing. Difference is presumably the opposite of commonality and vice versa. But grammatically, it's still two different words and two different ideas. If I said, "Freedom and liberty are ...", "freedom" and "liberty" are synonyms but it's still two words and thus should take the plural "are". You wouldn't say "Freedom and liberty is ..." Or "Physical fitness and athletic ability are ..." Etc.

The one caution I would give is that if you are talking about the words themselves, then you might speak of it as one thing. Like, "'Commonality and difference' is the subject of the sentence."